# Highlight/select first visible item in QListView when filtering with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, view, model, pyqt, pyside

If a list selection does not exist for filtered results then I would like to automatically highlight the first item. I created the method `force_selection()` that highlight's the first item if nothing is selected. I am using the `QListView.selectionModel()` to determine the selection index. I have tried connecting `force_selection()` to the `QLineEdit` slots: `textEdited(QString)` and `textChanged(QString)`. However, it appears that there is a timing issue between textChanged and the proxy refreshing the `QListView`. Sometimes the selection is made while other times it disappears.

So how would I go about forcing a selection (blue highlight) during a proxy filter if the user has not made a selection yet? The idea behind my code is that the user searches for an item, the top item is the best result so it is selected (unless they manually select another item in the filter view).

[You can find an image of the problem here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv75xz86sddm3c9/qlistviewselection.png)

*Recreate issue:*

1. Execute sample script with Python 2.7
2. Do not select anything in the list (QLineEdit should have focus)
3. Search for 'Red2', slowly type 'R', 'e', 'd' --> Red1 and Red2 are visible and Red1 is highlighted
4. Finish the search by typing the number '2' --> Red2 is no longer highlighted/selected

**Final solution:**

```
    from PySide import QtCore
    from PySide import QtGui

    class SimpleListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

        def __init__(self, contents):
            super(SimpleListModel, self).__init__()
            self.contents = contents

        def rowCount(self, parent):
            return len(self.contents)

        def data(self, index, role):
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self.contents[index.row()])

    class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

            data = ['Red1', 'Red2', 'Blue', 'Yellow']
            self.model = SimpleListModel(data)

            self.view = QtGui.QListView(self)

            self.proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
            self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
            self.proxy.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
            self.proxy.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
            self.view.setModel(self.proxy)

            self.search = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            self.search.setFocus()

            layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
            layout.addWidget(self.search, 0, 0)
            layout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0)

            self.setLayout(layout)

            # Connect search to proxy model
            self.connect(self.search, QtCore.SIGNAL('textChanged(QString)'), 
                         self.proxy.setFilterFixedString)

            # Moved after connect for self.proxy.setFilterFixedString
            self.connect(self.search, QtCore.SIGNAL('textChanged(QString)'), 
                         self.force_selection)

            self.connect(self.search, QtCore.SIGNAL('returnPressed()'), 
                         self.output_index)

        # @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
        @QtCore.Slot(str)
        def force_selection(self, ignore):
            """ If user has not made a selection, then automatically select top item.
            """
            selection_model = self.view.selectionModel()
            indexes = selection_model.selectedIndexes()

            if not indexes:
                index = self.proxy.index(0, 0)
                selection_model.select(index, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)

        def output_index(self):
            print 'View Index:',self.view.currentIndex().row()
            print 'Selected Model Current Index:',self.view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
            print 'Selected Model Selected Index:',self.view.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys

        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Updated link to screenshot: http://imgur.com/PQq3knb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of `connect` calls. You connect `textChanged` to `force_selection` first, so it's called first. But at that time, filter is not processed and proxy is not updated. So you select an item that might soon be removed by filtering.

Just switch the order of `connect` calls.

By the way, you might want to reconsider your logic in `force_selection`. `currentIndex` doesn't necessarily correspond to selected indexes. You can observe that by typing `red2` and deleting `2`. You'll get both `Red1` and `Red2` selected. If you want to deal with `currentIndex` use `setCurrentIndex` instead of `select`. If you want to deal with selected indexes, then your condition should be based on `selectedRows` or `selectedIndexes`.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code to reflect your recommendations. I did not know the order of connect calls influenced the behavior.